# Removing / pushing down an image in search results

Tags: seo, search-results

There is an image of one of our staff that pops up in search results that is in relation to an old business that we don't really want featured.

Is there an approach to remove or try to push an image (or page for that matter) down in the SERP's / image SERP's?

Comment: Is it an image on your website? Or someone else's?

Comment: To address what I believe John Conde is saying: If the image is on your website and you do not wish for it to exist in SERPs you should have the image deleted from your web server. If it is on another website and web host that is not yours you should kindly ask the administrators of the site that contains this image to delete it. Once deleted, search engines will realize the image does not exist and will remove the image from SERPs. Total removal will take a while. A cached version of this image may remain on SERPs, over time this should cycle out of SERPs completely as well. Hope this helps!

Comment: @JohnConde - The image is on a news site, not owned by us.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make a request to [remove your own content from Google search results](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663416?hl=en), including a specific image. See this for more:  [Google Webmaster Tools - Remove an image from Google search results](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/181721).

If it's content from someone else's site and you want the image removed for legal reasons, you [can send a legal removal request](http://support.google.com/bin/static.py?&ts=1114905&page=ts.cs) to Google. If you want it removed for [personal reasons](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2744324?), you can use the tool here (see the last option):   [Issues with Google Search](http://support.google.com/websearch/bin/static.py?&ts=1209905&page=ts.cs).