# How to remove a cache of a page with an offline photo within a website using Google Content Removal tool?

Tags: google, google-search-console, google-search

By using [Google's Content Removal](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/removals) page, I could put in a request for removal, for example if a page is no longer online, changed or now gone, and submit it by **entering a word that no longer appears in the online page**.

My question is: how could I submit a **photo** to be removed that is no longer available on the online page?

I could still reverse image search a photo and it is still shown in Google search results.

Clarification: I'm trying to remove cached page results of some websites using reverse image search. I have the now deleted (offline) url of the old picture from these sites. I don't know how to use the Google Content Removal tool because usually for these cache removals you type in a **word that is no longer on the online page**, but in my scenario it's **a photo I'm trying to convey is no longer on the page.** So what should I type in when Google asks me to enter a word that's not on the online page?

Here's screen shot as requested:
[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with the "type in a word that is no longer on the online page."   Could you include a screenshot of this so we can see it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can read in my previous answer [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/50856/removing-pushing-down-an-image-in-search-results/50862#50862), you can [remove an image from Google search results](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/181721) by:

> 1. Click the image that you locate in the image search results.
> 2. Right-click View original image or Full size, and copy the link address.
> 3. Paste the URL into a file or document, so it’s available when you use the URL removal tool.
>
> Once you have the URL ready, follow the [instructions for removing an entire page](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1663419).

Which are:

> 1. On the Webmaster Tools home page, click the site you want.
> 2. On the Dashboard, click **Google Index** on the left-hand menu.
> 3. Click **Remove URLs**.
> 4. Click **New removal request**.
> 5. Type the URL of the page you want removed from search results (not the Google search results URL or cached page URL), and then click
>    **Continue**. [How to find the right URL](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/63758). The URL is case-sensitive—use
>    exactly the same characters and capitalization that the site uses.
> 6. Click **Yes, remove this page**.
> 7. Click **Submit Request**.

As indicated there:

> To ensure your content is permanently removed, you need to do one of
> the following within 90 days of requesting removal. Otherwise, your
> content may later reappear in search results. ([More information about
> blocking Google](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93708).)
>
> - If the page no longer exists, make sure that the server returns a 404
>   (Not Found) or 410 (Gone) [HTTP status code](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/40132). Non-HTML file (like PDFs)
>   should be completely removed from your server.
> - If the page still
>   exists, use [robots.txt](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/156449) to prevent Google from crawling it. Even if a
>   URL is disallowed by robots.txt we may still index the page if we find
>   its URL on another site. However, we won't index the page if it's
>   blocked in robots.txt and there is an active URL removal request for
>   the page.

**As tested, if you follow the above steps you will *not* be asked to:** "Type a word that no longer appears on the live page, but is still in the cached version."

If you continue to have problems removing an image from Google's search results, you can use the [Problems with Google Search](https://support.google.com/websearch/troubleshooter/3425345?rd=2) tool, selecting the last option there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Google's regular content removal system the same way you would remove a page. Submit a full URL to the image and it should get removed just like a page would.

https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/181721

Comment: Hi but my photo is not in the "image" results of search, it's on a page. The picture I'm trying to remove is a profile picture on a site, for example, on tumblr or deviantart. Do I submit the url to the tumblr page? Thanks

Comment: @Natalie just submit the URL of the photo then

Comment: but what do I type for this question? "If you want to remove the cache, tell Google how the page has changed. Type a word that no longer appears on the live page, but is still in the cached version."